# public inherited class not able to access overloaded non-virtual public method of base class?

Tags: c++, inheritance, overloading

My compiler says:

```
error C2660: 'UberMaterial::Initialize' : function does not take 2 arguments
```

When I write this:

```
#include "BaseMaterial.h"
#include "UberMaterial.h"

UberMaterial* m_pGameLevelMaterial;
m_pGameLevelMaterial->Initialize(m_pContentManager, m_pLevel->GetDevice());
```

**The base class:**

```
class BaseMaterial
{
public:
BaseMaterial(tstring shaderFilename);
virtual ~BaseMaterial(){}

void Initialize(ContentManager *pContentManager, ID3D10Device *pD3DDevice);
//[More Code...]

protected:
    virtual void Initialize(ContentManager *pContentManager) = 0;
//[More Code...]
};
```

**The inherited class:**

```
#include "BaseMaterial.h"
class UberMaterial:public BaseMaterial
{
//[More Code...]
protected:
    virtual void Initialize(ContentManager *pContentManager);
//[More Code...]
};
```

Can anyone tell me what the problem is?

*If you need more code, just comment and I'll post it. But the whole thing is rather large, so I didn't include it at this point.*

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, by default, an overload in a derived class will hide a different overload from a base class.  You can re-expose the base-class overload with `using`:

```
class UberMaterial : public BaseMaterial
{
    ...

public:
    using BaseMaterial::Initialize;

    virtual void Initialize(ContentManager *pContentManager);
};
```

Comment: I'm using virtual because the method is overloaded in the base class, and I want that overloaded method to be accessed via polymorphism in other code.

I'm not sure if I understand your answer though. By putting using `BaseMaterial::Initialize` there, I will be able to access the method of the base class?

Comment: Ah nvm I understand since your last edit. But what does a `using` declaration do inside a class? Btw, I could also access it by typing `m_pGameLevelMaterial->BaseMaterial::Initialize(m_pContentManager, m_pLevel->GetDevice());`

Comment: @xcrypt : `using` brings a base member into scope when it would be otherwise hidden.

Comment: @ildjarn But you have to access it outside of the class, by calling a method on an instance of the class? It seems more logical to me not to put it in the class?

Comment: @xcrypt : I have no idea what you mean; it seems more logical to you to not put an `Initialize` member function in your class? Aren't you the one that put it there?